# Flutter, Firebase | In the flutter fire documentation fromJson and toJson functions

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, class

I'm a beginner so this question may sound trivial to you experts but i'm unable to understand the concept here. pls help
In the [Flutter Fire documentation, in CollectionReference and DocumentReference segment](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#typing-collectionreference-and-documentreference)

```dart
  Movie({required this.title, required this.genre});

  Movie.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) // Here Movie.fromJson is created
    : this(
        title: json['title']! as String,
        genre: json['genre']! as String,
      );

  final String title;
  final String genre;

// What if i create fromJson like this. would it be valid?
// and upper function is just a simplified version of this
Object fromJson (Map<String, Object?> json) {
    return (
        title: json['title']! as String,
        genre: json['genre']! as String,);

  }

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() { // Here toJson is created differently
    return {
      'title': title,
      'genre': genre,
    };
  }

}

//Further they are used like this

final moviesRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('movies').withConverter<Movie>(
      fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Movie.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
      toFirestore: (movie, _) => movie.toJson(),
    );
```

Why fromJson and toJson are created differently

Comment: Because one takes a map to convert into an object and the other needs to use the variables from the object to turn into a map

Comment: `toJson` converts `Movie` to a `Map` (to store in firestore), while `fromJson` converts the `Map` to the `Movie` (for easy use in flutter)

Comment: yes, i understood the conversion differences. edited my question to elaborate the doubt further

Comment: Does my answer, answer your question?

Comment: Thanks @PeterO. I'm revisiting this concept and I think it is making sense to me now. Have been pondering over this - some tutorials use `fromDocument` method some uses `fromJSON` little confusing in the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toJson` converts `Movie` to a `Map` (to store in firestore), while `fromJson` converts the `Map` to the `Movie` (for easy use in flutter).

withConverter helps retain type safety, by automatically converting firebase's `Map` to `Movie` and back.